# UICollectionviewCell backgroundColor not Change when selected

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm trying to change backgorund color of cell when its selected. But cell background color not changing.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CategoryCollectionViewCell
    let category = self.categories[indexPath.row]
    switch cell.isSelected {
    case true:
        cell.backgroundColor = .black
    default:
        cell.backgroundColor = .white
    }
    cell.setNeedsDisplay()    
}
```

Comment: **cell.backgroundColor = cell.isSelected ? .black : .white** will be better than **switch**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to manually change the background color upon selection. UICollectionViewCell has a property called [`selectedBackgroundView`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicollectionviewcell/1620138-selectedbackgroundview) precisely for this purpose.

Use it in your `collectionView(_:cellForItemAt:)` delegate method as follows:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CategoryCollectionViewCell

    cell.selectedBackgroundView = UIView(frame: cell.bounds)
    cell.selectedBackgroundView!.backgroundColor = .black

    return cell
}
```

Comment: UICollectionViewCell shows `backgroundView` when the cell is not selected and shows `selectedBackgroundView` when the cell is selected. So assuming you have already configured the `backgroundView` property with a view set to your default background color, you don't need to do anything more to change the background color apart from deselecting the cell.

Comment: but its not changin on second click

Comment: When clicking for a second time, are you selecting a different cell or the same cell?

Comment: I'm selecting same cell

Comment: Selecting the same cell twice won't _deselect_ the cell, so if you want the second click to have that effect, you'll need to write some more code.  There are many existing questions and answers on the topic of deselecting collection view cells (such as [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35184126)).

Answer (score 3):

Try the following in you didSelect delegate method:

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let selectedCell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath)

    selectedCell?.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) {
        cell.backgroundColor = cell.isSelected ? .black : .white
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think handling of background colour of a cell should be a part of a cell by observing its property `isSelected`. It handles both selection and un-selection of a cell otherwise it would be tricky to un-select a selected cell at selection of any other cell e.g:

```
class MyCustomCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    override var isSelected: Bool {
        didSet {
            contentView.backgroundColor = isSelected ? .red : .white
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Kudos! This is the best flexible solution.

Answer (score 0):

You should make use of two of the collection view delegate methods as follow:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

  let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CategoryCollectionViewCell

  cell.backgroundColor = .black
}
```

And,

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

  let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CategoryCollectionViewCell

  cell.backgroundColor = .white
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    
    let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! CustomCell
    cell.cellView.backgroundColor = .red
    
}
```

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign selected and normal background views on the custom cell level. This is what Apple actually recommends, here is their own sample and link to apple's docs:

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
super.awakeFromNib()
    
    let redView = UIView(frame: bounds)
    redView.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1)
    self.backgroundView = redView

    let blueView = UIView(frame: bounds)
    blueView.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
    self.selectedBackgroundView = blueView
}
```

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdelegate/changing_the_appearance_of_selected_and_highlighted_cells